# Output same JSON as in ApiController in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to output JSON directly in my Razor view. The object being serialized is `IEnumerable<ItemDto>` (see definition below). I want to serialize it to identical JSON that would be returned from an `ApiController`. Here is what I have tried:

- When using `@Json.Encode(theValue)`, it ignores the `DataMember`, so the properties get the wrong names (uppercase first letter).
- When using `DataContractJsonSerializer` (and castingthe `IEnumerable<ItemDto>` to `IList<ItemDto>`), it outputs the `ImageDto.Sizes` as `[{ Key: 'foo', Value: <object> }]`, but the ApiController correctly does `{ 'foo': <object> }`.

Here are my classes:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class ItemDto
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "image")]
        public ImageDto Image { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "price")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ImageDto
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "sizes")]
        public Dictionary<String, ImageSizeDto> Sizes { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ImageSizeDto
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "w")]
        public int Width { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "h")]
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }
```

The objective is to avoid a separate `GET` request for data that is necessary on almost every page.

Desired JSON:

```
[{"id":6,
 "title":"Foo bar baz",
 "image":
    {"id":"fb2a3b4a-5ae5-4d9d-baff-72e107aa6e9c",
     "sizes":
        {"Original": {"url":"http://example.com/a", "w":-1, "h":-1},
         "Thumbnail": {"url":"http://example.com/b", "w":130, "h":73},
         "LargeThumbnail": {"url":"http://example.com/c", "w":220,"h":124},
         "Popup": {"url":"http://example.com/d", "w":256, "h":256},
         "FullWidth": {"url":"http://example.com/e", "w":930, "h":524}}},
 "price":79}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
[DataContract]
public class ItemDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "image")]
    public ImageDto Image { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ImageDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "sizes")]
    public Dictionary<String, ImageSizeDto> Sizes { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ImageSizeDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "w")]
    public int Width { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "h")]
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var items = new[] 
        {
            new ItemDto
            {
                Id = 6,
                Title = "Foo bar baz",
                Image = new ImageDto
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Sizes = new Dictionary<string, ImageSizeDto>
                    {
                        { "Original", new ImageSizeDto { Url = "http://example.com/a", Width = -1, Height = -1 } },
                        { "Thumbnail", new ImageSizeDto { Url = "http://example.com/b", Width = 130, Height = 73 } },
                    },
                },
                Price = 79
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items));
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Foo bar baz",
        "image": {
            "id": "6a1c1d34-3e78-4303-8edd-d8541dd915e7",
            "sizes": {
                "Original": {
                    "url": "http://example.com/a",
                    "w": -1,
                    "h": -1
                },
                "Thumbnail": {
                    "url": "http://example.com/b",
                    "w": 130,
                    "h": 73
                }
            }
        },
        "price": 79
    }
]
```

Note that in the ASP.NET MVC 4 RTM Json.Net will be the [default serialzier](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx). Until then simply swap the built-in serializer with Json.NET as illustrated in the Scott Hanselman's blog post.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know how awesome Json.Net was until now... :)

Comment: @Darin, Do you have any reference for saying that MVC 4 RTM will be using JSON.NET?  I've found plenty saying that Web API uses it (and can confirm that in the RC this is the case), but it still appears that MVC 4 uses DataContractSerializer.  I wouldn't expect something this significant to change between RC + RTM.

Comment: @Richard, didn't you read my answer? There's a link to this reference I provided in it: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx. I quote Hanselman in case you haven't read it: `We on the web team will be including JSON.NET as the default JSON Serializer in Web API when it releases, so that'll be nice.`

Comment: Included in your quote: "in Web API".  In your answer you said it would be default in MVC.  While Web API makes up part of ASP.NET MVC4, they're not the same thing.  Json.Encode from a View page in MVC4 RC uses DataContractSerializer.  Web API uses JSON.NET

Comment: Ah sorry if you misunderstood my answer. Json.NET will be the default serializer for the Web API. Dunno for ASP.NET MVC. For me it's the default serializer since the early ages so I don't really care if it will be the default or not :-) If it is the default all I have to do is remove my custom extension methods that are currently replacing the JavaScriptSerializer with Json.NET. If it isn't I simply keep them.